# Send data to Python thread, then read a response using Queue

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

It's quite easy to send or receive data through threads using Queue's module when doing each thing at a time, but I didn't figure out how to send something to a thread, then expect for a return properly.

In the below example, I was expecting to send something to thread in order to be processed, then harvest the result, but the `t.queue.get()` in the main function receives what what just sent above instead of waiting for the thread to return. How can I get around it?

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue

class MyThread(Thread):
    queue:Queue

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.queue = Queue()
        self.daemon = True

    # receives a name, then prints "Hello, name!"
    def run(self):
        while True:
            val = self.queue.get()
            if not val:
                break

            self.queue.put(f'Hello, {val}!')

def main():
    t = MyThread()
    t.start()

    # sends string to thread
    t.queue.put('Jurandir')

    # expects to receive "Hello, Jurandir!",
    # but "Jurandir" is immediately returned
    ret = t.queue.get()

    print(ret)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Two queues. One for each direction (main->worker, worker->main)?

Comment: @Aaron, don't thought of this possibility. It worked fine, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thing is that you are getting the alleged result immediately from the queue, and the worker has still not added the result. You can split into an "input queue" and a "results queue". And then wait in the main thread until there's some output in the queue.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from threading import Thread, Lock
from queue import Queue


class MyThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.input_queue = Queue()
        self.results_queue = Queue()

        self.daemon = True

    # receives a name, then prints "Hello, name!"
    def run(self):
        while True:
            val = self.input_queue.get()

            if not val:
                break

            self.results_queue.put(f'Hello, {val}!')


def main():
    t = MyThread()
    t.start()

    # sends string to thread
    t.input_queue.put('Jurandir')

    ret = t.results_queue.get()
    while ret is None:
        ret = t.results_queue.get()
    print(ret)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```